# South Indian Vaishnava temple tradition of blessing with a conical cap (kirita)

Tags: temple

While having "darshanam" in South Indian Vaishnav temples, the priest keeps a  conical cap (kirita) on devotee's head.
What might be the significance of this tradition?

Comment: Are you talking about Vaishnava temples?? In Shiva temples that chadari is not there!

Comment: I have also seen this in Iskon temples but don't know the reason.

Comment: @AkshayKumarS I have edited the Q to include the word "Vaishnav".

Comment: @Destroyer I could not find it because I didn't know that it is called "Sadagopuram". Anyways, thanks...

Comment: It's called a Shatagopam. Shatagopuram is not correct pronunciation.